# Can't acces localhost trough LAN

Tags: server, firewall, private, lan

Local http server on pc using express is not discoverable to any other device on lan.

On the phone's browser I entered the private ip of the pc with the correct port, but the phone was not finding the pc's server.

Tried setting up inbound rules in Firewall - did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the wifi that the pc was connected to was set to "Public network" so that is why nothing was exposed to lan

[image: Image of the setting]